# JSON.parse changes sorting - Ruby

Tags: ruby, json, parsing, sorting

In the code below, the order of my items gets changed after the JSON.parse(f) line, i.e., this hash:

{
a => aval,
b => bval,
c => cval,
d => dval
}

becomes something like:

{
b => bval,
c => cval,
a => aval,
d => dval
}

This is a problem because my display code just reads from the json file, so any time I save back to it, and then display, everything gets changed around. Is there anything I can do to retain the order?

CODE:

```
  f = File.read($PLAN_DESC_PATH)
  puts ("f " + f.to_s())
  hash = JSON.parse(f)
  puts ("hash " +  hash.to_s())
```

My Ruby version is 1.8.7. I am using Sinatra.  I believe I got the JSON gem from here: http://flori.github.com/json/ (sorry, kinda new to this).  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ruby 1.8.7 the Hash class does not maintain order either by keys or by order added. If you need something like that, you would need to implement something like ActiveSupport::OrderedHash (http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/ActiveSupport/OrderedHash)

In Ruby 1.9.x hashes are ordered by when they are inserted by default (see http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html)

When you serialize a hash to JSON, all bets are off for maintaining order of your keys. You'll need some post processing after your serialization to ensure order if that's necessary for you.

Answer (score 2):

No, *hashmaps* are not meant to have a specific ordering. If you need ordering use something different like an *array*. Or extract all the keys, sort them like you want and then you can have what order you like.

Making assumptions on ordering inside maps is anyway something on which you shouldn't rely, that's the fact.

A good alternative would be to have:

```
[ [a, aval], [b, bval], ... ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Jack answered for Ruby, so I'll answer for JSON.  From [RFC 4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) (emphasis added):

"An object is an *unordered* collection of zero or more name/value pairs"

Comment: My answer was related on data structures in general, wasn't thinking about Ruby :) But you are welcome! Normally hashmaps are always unordered, no matter what is the language

Comment: @Jack, true, with a notable exception being, as always, PHP.  But it's good to refer to the standards too.